# Why is the context node getting output twice?

Tags: xml, xslt

To eliminate internal para elements, but put a br element between subsequent para elements in an itemizedlist, given xml like the following:

```
    <listitem>
        <para>The application of power invokes the POR state machine(PORSM). During
        this time, the following registers are initialized:</para>
        .
        .
        .
        <para>In addition, the JTAG interface is disabled and the SSBD is
        open.</para>
     </listitem>
```

I wrote a template like the following:

```
 <xsl:template match="listitem/para">
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
<xsl:if test="count(./following-sibling::para) > 0">
<xsl:element name="br"/> 
</xsl:if>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
```

I get the br, but the initial para element is repeated:

```
  The application of power invokes the POR state machine
        (PORSM). During this time, the following registers are
        initialized:
    <br/>The application of power invokes the POR state machine
        (PORSM). During this time, the following registers are
        initialized:
```

I know this is a newbie question, but can someone explain why i am getting the current text node repeated?

thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first copy comes from the

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

and the second from

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

which applies templates to all child nodes of the `para` element.  Child nodes include text nodes as well as element nodes, and if you haven't specified an explicit template to match `text()` then the default template for text nodes will output the text to the result tree.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 

So is having an explicit template to match text() the preferred/elegant manner to handle this?

I looked through some previous code i had, and in a similar situation, i used something like:

 <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::para)]"/>

rather than

 <xsl:apply-templates/>

And that seemed to work, but it just seemed inelegant.

Comment: @RussUrquhart the "best" approach depends on the stylesheet and the task.  If you're writing a stylesheet whose job is to "modify" some XML (i.e. to keep the structure more or less the same as the original) then the recommended approach is to start with an _identity template_ that copies input to output verbatim and then override it selectively.  In that case you would prefer the `apply-templates` approach over explicit `value-of` expressions.  But conversely if you're building a brand new structure with bits of data extracted from the original then the `value-of` approach can be easier.

Comment: @RussUrquhart remember that `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is equivalent to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />`, which is broader than `select="*"` - the former selects all elements, text nodes, comments and processing instructions, the latter only elements.